# Get latest voucher number DynamicsGPClient

Tags: vb.net, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-gp

Is it possible to get the next voucher number for a payable transaction via DynamicsGPClient?

I can do a lookup but this voucher result is a few records old.

```
    Dim PayablesInvoiceCriteria As New PayablesInvoiceCriteria() With {.Date = New BetweenRestrictionOfNullableOfdateTime() With {.GreaterThan = Date.now}}
    Dim InvoiceSummaries As PayablesInvoiceSummary() = wsDynamicsGP.GetPayablesInvoiceList(PayablesInvoiceCriteria, context)
    Dim Last = InvoiceSummaries(InvoiceSummaries.Length - 1).Key.Id
```

Comment: Do you mean the most recently used voucher? Or the next available? The keys are saved in PM00400 table and they are created/generated when a user starts a transaction. They become "permanent" in the keys table when the user saves the record. So the behavior you are seeing is probably related to that process. This person seems to have a workaround for you by calling eConnect and the `GETNEXTNUMBER` stored proc directly: https://carldesouza.com/get-next-document-number-econnect/ reference to the GP eConnect schema here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff623620.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of info on how the key generation works for transactions in GP. The keys are saved in PM00400 table, and they are created/generated when a user starts a transaction. They become "permanent" in the keys table when the user saves the record. So the behavior you are seeing is probably related to that process.

I am not sure if this can be done without eConnect. So my suggestion, as a workaround, you can use the eConnect namespace.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff623620.aspx

**Class**

```
Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.eConnect.GetNextDocNumbers
```

**Syntax**

```
public virtual string GetPMNextVoucherNumber(
    GetNextDocNumbers.IncrementDecrement incDec,
    string connString
)
```

**Example**

```
Dim connString as String = string.Empty
Dim sqlserver as String = "localhost"
Dim database as String = "TWO"

connString = "data source=" + sqlserver + ";" + "initial catalog=" + database + ";" + "Integrated Security=SSPI;"

Dim NextDocNumber as New String
Dim getNextDocNumbers = new Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.eConnect.GetNextDocNumbers()
NextDocNumber = getNextDocNumbers.GetPMNextVoucherNumber(Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.eConnect.IncrementDecrement.Increment, connString)
```

Additional examples can be found here:

https://carldesouza.com/get-next-document-number-econnect/

Comment: Thanks Jacob. I have a working PoC with your example.